# Earth's surface area

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, earth

> Here we are trying to calculate the earth's surface area via geodetic coordinates:
>   \begin{align}
> x&=(R\,p(\lambda)+h)\sin\lambda\,\cos\phi\\
> y&=(R\,p(\lambda)+h)\sin\lambda\,\sin\phi\\ 
> z&=[(1-e^2)R\,p(\lambda)+h]\cos\lambda
> \end{align}
>   where 
>   $$p(\lambda)=\frac 1 {\sqrt{1-e^2\cos ^2 \lambda}}$$
>
> We first compute the flat metric $ds^2$ in these coordinates:
>   $$ds^2=dh^2+{[h+(1-e^2)R\,p^3]}^2 d\lambda ^2+{\sin^2\!\lambda\,(h+Rp)^2 d\phi^2}$$
>
> Then we compute induced metric on the surface by putting $h=0$
>   $$ds_*^2=R^2p^2[(1-e^2)^2p^4 d\lambda ^2+\sin ^2\!\lambda\,d\phi ^2]$$
>
> where the determinant of this metric is $g_*=R^4p^8(1-e^2)^2\sin ^2\lambda$
>
> We found that 
>   \begin{align}
> A&=\int\sqrt{g_*}\,d\phi\,d\lambda\\&=2\pi R^2(1-e^2) \left[\frac{1}{1-e^2}+\frac{\tanh^{-1}\!e}{e}\right]\\&=2\pi R^2\left[1+ \left(\frac{1}{e}-e\right)\tanh^{-1}\!e\right]\end{align}
>
> $$e=0 \implies A=4\pi R ^2$$ and $$e\approx 0 \implies A\approx 4\pi R ^2 - \frac 4 3 \pi R^2 e^2 + O(e^4),$$

So from here, how do we get that for the Earth:

$$A_\text {ellipsoid}=5.10\times 10^8 \mathrm{km}^2$$ and $$A_\text{sphere}=5.12\times 10^8 \mathrm{km}^2$$

Plugging $e=0.0791$, $R_S=6380 $ into the formula I get $A_{sphere}=510439776.2$ instead of $5.12\times 10^8 km^2$
Similarly, plugging $e=0.0791$, $R_E=6360 $ into the formula I get $A_{ellipsoid}=507244542.9$ instead of $5.10\times 10^8 km^2$

Comment: the conclusion should come by a taylor expansion of the "exact" computation around $e=0$.

Comment: for $e\mapsto 0$ I don't get the $A=4\pi\,R^2$  and then taylor  expansion doesn't exist for your function!. Is your integration result correct? I get with symbolic manipulation program difference  result .